# Force a data type to be a FloatType()/DecimalType in PySpark

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I have to extract data from REST API ([Odata](https://www.odata.org/documentation/odata-version-2-0/overview/)). Some data type are defined as float/decimal but all the values are integer. However, I would like to keep float/decimal without modifying the content. Here is a reproducible example:

```
from pyspark.sql import Row
from pyspark.sql.types import *

MyData = {'@odata.context': "my_url",
 'value': [{'@odata.etag': 'W/"JzIwOzE3NjQxOTY2ODQyODAwNjIyNzM0MTswMDsn"',
   'id': '8e3a9c6b-0bfd-ec11-82f8-000d3ac6cca7',
   'ITEM_NUMBER': '390_10000001',
   'ITEM_NM': 'BARIUM SULPHATE (BSP-L)  ',
   'AZelis_Base_Product': '1B002-25L',
   'MANUACTURER_NUMBER': '20000009',
   'MANUFACTURER_NM': 'GEMME NANO TECH (CANTON) CO., LTD.',
   'PACKAGE': '25 KG / BAG',
   'BATCH_ID': '2111242',
   'EXPIRY_DATE': '2022-11-24',
   'LAST_RECEIPT_DATE_SAME_BATCH': '2021-12-26',
   'WAREHOUSE': 'NSW-CM',
   'SITE': '390',
   'DEPARTMENT': '101',
   'STOCK_QUANTITY_KG': 725,
   'Stock_Value_EUR': 452.37727,
   'QUANTITY_KG_OPEN_SO_ORDERS': 0,
   'QUANTITY_KG_OPEN_PO_ORDERS': 0,
   'QUANTITY_KG_SOLD_L12M': 33750,
   'BOM_QUANTITY_KG_SOLD_L12M': 0},
  {'@odata.etag': 'W/"JzE5Ozk1MDE4NzAwNDQwMzg2Mjk0ODkxOzAwOyc="',
   'id': '8f3a9c6b-0bfd-ec11-82f8-000d3ac6cca7',
   'ITEM_NUMBER': '390_10000001',
   'ITEM_NM': 'BARIUM SULPHATE (BSP-L)  ',
   'AZelis_Base_Product': '1B002-25L',
   'MANUACTURER_NUMBER': '20000009',
   'MANUFACTURER_NM': 'GEMME NANO TECH (CANTON) CO., LTD.',
   'PACKAGE': '25 KG / BAG',
   'BATCH_ID': '2203152',
   'EXPIRY_DATE': '2023-03-15',
   'LAST_RECEIPT_DATE_SAME_BATCH': '2022-04-11',
   'WAREHOUSE': 'NSW-CM',
   'SITE': '390',
   'DEPARTMENT': '101',
   'STOCK_QUANTITY_KG': 20250,
   'Stock_Value_EUR': 12635.36518,
   'QUANTITY_KG_OPEN_SO_ORDERS': 0,
   'QUANTITY_KG_OPEN_PO_ORDERS': 0,
   'QUANTITY_KG_SOLD_L12M': 33750,
   'BOM_QUANTITY_KG_SOLD_L12M': 0}]}

my_schema = StructType(
                [
                    StructField(
                        "@odata.context",StringType(),False)
                        ,StructField("value"
                            ,ArrayType(
                                StructType(
                                    [
                                        StructField("@odata.etag",StringType(),False)
                                        ,StructField("id",StringType(),False)
                                        ,StructField("ITEM_NUMBER",StringType(),True)
                                        ,StructField("ITEM_NM",StringType(),True)
                                        ,StructField("AZelis_Base_Product",StringType(),True)
                                        ,StructField("MANUACTURER_NUMBER",StringType(),True)
                                        ,StructField("MANUFACTURER_NM",StringType(),True)
                                        ,StructField("PACKAGE",StringType(),True)
                                        ,StructField("BATCH_ID",StringType(),True)
                                        ,StructField("EXPIRY_DATE",StringType(),True)
                                        ,StructField("LAST_RECEIPT_DATE_SAME_BATCH",StringType(),True)
                                        ,StructField("WAREHOUSE",StringType(),True)
                                        ,StructField("SITE",StringType(),True)
                                        ,StructField("DEPARTMENT",StringType(),True)
                                        ,StructField("STOCK_QUANTITY_KG",DecimalType(),True)
                                        ,StructField("Stock_Value_EUR",DecimalType(),True)
                                        ,StructField("QUANTITY_KG_OPEN_SO_ORDERS",DecimalType(),True)
                                        ,StructField("QUANTITY_KG_OPEN_PO_ORDERS",DecimalType(),True)
                                        ,StructField("QUANTITY_KG_SOLD_L12M",DecimalType(),True)
                                        ,StructField("BOM_QUANTITY_KG_SOLD_L12M",DecimalType(),True)
                                    ]
                                    )
                                ,True
                            )
                        ,True
                    )
                ]
            )

df_MyData=spark.createDataFrame(Row(MyData), my_schema)
```

I have the following error:

```
TypeError: field STOCK_QUANTITY_KG in element in array field value: DecimalType(10,0) can not accept object 725 in type <class 'int'>
```

I don't want to change the decimal/float type into integer because it has been defined like this. I don't want to modify the content the data. How can I solve this issue?

Comment: If you don't want to modify your schema, then you should change your `STOCK_QUANTITY_KG ` data type to `decimal` in `MyData` dictionary

Comment: Hello Jonathan, there is really no way to force the schema without modifying the content?

Comment: if you force spark to parse with the given data type, spark will set it to null. so, there aren't a lot of things you could do here.

Answer (score 0):

I would heavily recommend changing the schema or the data, the reason for that is Pyspark will set mismatching types to `null`s.

For example, we can use the `verifySchema = False` parameter to the `createDataFrame` call to "force" the schema. Which we can verify by calling `printSchema()` on the dataframe.

However, if you print the data with `show(truncate=False)` you will find all the originally-integer values to be `null`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I understand that integer is an integer. However, if I change the data type to integer and I have one day, decimal value, PySpark will trow an error again, right? If I have really no choice, I will convert the decimal type as a string and cast it as float

Comment: Yes, it will throw an error. However, I prefer having Pyspark scream in my face rather than having a database filled with nulls. If your API returns a JSON, you can change the types with Python's built-in `int()` or `float()`, since they don't throw errors or return nulls like Pyspark, before creating the dataframe. The other solution is reading everything as a string and then casting with the help of `round` or `split`  from `pyspark.sql.function` which can be more efficient than using builtins if the API returns thousands of responses per request.